# Yoast SEO - disable OpenGraph Tags for a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, yoast

Our WordPress theme adds relevant Opengraph Tags on Custom Post Type (job_listings) created by it while it does not add on other standard posts and pages.

Wondering if there is a way to turn off Yoast's Opengraph tags on this specific post type since we now have duplicate og: tags on all posts of this post type.